# "Path not found" error in VBScript when creating a file

Tags: vbscript

I am making a simple VBS application which has a bit where it creates a file in the startup directory. When I did it a while back, it worked, but I've since updated my code and need it to do other things too.

This is the code that creates the file:

```
Dim fso, openFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\startup\file.bat"
```

It gives some sort of error saying it does not know where to go, I don't know if there's a problem with the file path I've supplied, because `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` is a folder, obviously. I've also just discovered that there is no `startup\` folder in it, is that what's causing it?

If so, is there something I can specify that creates the directory if it does not exist?

I'm very new to VBS and I have a *very* limited knowledge of it, so a simple way to do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can't write to `ProgramData` without adminstrator privileges.

Comment: @KenWhite That's a good point, I forgot that. I also know there is one in the user's AppData folder, but to make the script work on an account with any name all I can think of is `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\startup`, which I tried but I think the percentage signs mess it up somehow and it needs a path starting with `C:\`. Do you know of any other way to get to that path without using the `%AppData%` shortcut?

Comment: @Toydotgam The FileSystemObject doesn’t automatically expand environment variables you need to first use the `ExpandEnvironmentString()` method to get the underlying value and concatenate it into the path string.

Comment: @Lankymart Oh okay, there's a thing to do that, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Is the filepath correct? (can you find it mannualy?) If yes, then try to copy the path in a variable and call the variable with the path.

```
Dim fso, openFile
Dim filepath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\startup\file.bat"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile(filepath)
```

And also make sure, that the file don't exists before you start the programm.

Good Luck

Jonas

Comment: Okay, this seems like a good alternative way, but I'll end up using a different directory because I forgot that `C:\ProgramData\` can't be written to without elevation, as @KenWhite also said. But I'll try some alternative ways and see where I get! Thanks.